# User profile not showing it's data

Tags: mysql, profile

I want to create a user details page and I have created this code check this code and it's errors and please tell me what I should do to make it right and if you are giving me any code to add in my code then kindly tell me where I put that code.

**It's giving me following errors**

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address


Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 36
View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address

View All Details
ID  Username    Password    Name    Address
```

**and Here is my code:**

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])){
        header("location:index.php");
    }

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){

header("location: index.php");
}
else {

?>


<?php
$username = "root";
    $password = "123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

$query = "select * from users";

$run = (mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error));

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $address = $row['address']; 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Details</title>
    </head>

<body>
<table width="1000" border="2" align="center" bgcolor="pink"> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10" align="center" bgcolor="yellow"><h1>View All Details</h1></td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="orange">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
<tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $address; ?></td>


    </tr>
<?php } ?>


</table>


</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Change `$run = mysql_query($query);` to `$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);` so it could give you the output for the error and post it.
And please use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and not `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Same error after doing this @OrelEraki

Comment: Your $password and $username after connecting to db get overwritten later,I don`t think that`s the problem but you should pick other names.

Comment: @user3023297, Can you put please `or die(mysql_error())` after every mysql..() command. And please share the output. (i forgot in the first comment to use parenthesis).

Comment: I have put `$run = (mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error));` but now it's giving me this error
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 30` @OrelEraki

Comment: @user3023297, We need you to edit your original code and output every time you doing a change. So we can follow up. Additionally the Notice messages aren't errors so don't stress up it's just "wamp" notice messages that can be easily ignored.

Comment: how can I ignore notice messages? btw what does this notice mean? `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 30` @OrelEraki

Comment: @user3023297, I've told you to use "mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` additionally the Notice messages can be solved by replacing the line "error_reporting = E_ALL" by "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE" at php.ini (php configuration file).
And **Please** edit your post and publish the new changed code and output messages.

Comment: @user3023297, this `$run = (mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error));` isn't good. this `$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` is. Try it and show output.

Comment: I have updated the error block above now I am getting these notices after adding `$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` @OrelEraki

Comment: @user3023297, if you're using the correct SQL column names than this should do the trick for you http://ideone.com/1Xhl4n

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha, You haven't connect to the database I supposed.
It should be

```
 $run = mysql_query($selected,$query);
```

Try this it should work because I just made a profile page today.

Hope it helps

Poom

Comment: After doing this not it's giving me these errors 
`Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 28`

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\user_details.php on line 30`

Comment: Do you have any data in the mysql database?

Comment: Yeah I have data in my data base   Database: login Table: users and it has id,username,password,Name,address

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not error it is notice, it produces when you use WAMP software.
either just define variable

```
$id = '';
$username ='';
$password = '';
$name = '';
$address=''; 
before while loop
```

or turn off notice ; Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Have you add these variable before loop;